# d3.js - image `mouseenter` stopPropagation throw error

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a group. the group contains `text`,`arc` and `image`. on `mouseenter` i would like to add the `stropPropagation` to the event. (since every time the mouse mouse on text event triggers.)

so I added the `d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();` method. but it throws error as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined` what is wrong here?

code :

```
d3.selectAll('.subAppGroupDetail image')
    .on('mouseenter', function (e) {
        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
        $('.quickView').show(500);
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    $('.quickView').hide(100);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this:

```
  d3.selectAll('.subAppGroupDetail image')
   .on('mouseover', function (e) {
                d3.event.stopPropagation();
                $('.quickView').show(500);
   })
  .on('mouseout', function (e) {
           d3.event.stopPropagation();
           $('.quickView').hide(100);
  })
```